# Angularjs error in call $scope.$apply()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

An error occurs when you call $digest or apply

```
  registerAjax = ->
    successRegister = ->
      $scope.showRegistrationPanel = false
      $scope.showEndRegistrationPanel = true
      $scope.$digest()
   errorRegister = (response) ->
      $scope.textErrorPanelRegistration = response.data.error
      $scope.showErrorPanel = true
      $scope.$apply()



   data =
     password: $scope.user.password
     firstName: $scope.user.firstName
    lastName: $scope.user.lastName
    email: $scope.user.email

   http.post REGISTER_URL, data
    .then successRegister, errorRegister
```

when calling $digest or $apply the error takes off but it all works

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.7/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
at Error (native)
at http://localhost:8000/lib/angular/angular.min.js?M420gm3LwzcQLAcaXrk6IQ:6:416
```

Comment: Are you using `jQuery.ajax` in your code..then obviously you need to run digest cycle..or you could just try `$timeout(function(){})` for running safe digest cycle

Comment: So there is no need to run digest cycle..if you are using `$http` methods to make ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Angular's [$timeout service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout):

```
$timeout(function() {
  $scope.$apply();
});
```

This will automatically wait for the current digest cycle to complete before calling $apply.